# Verifying same apple receipt multiple times

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere. What happens if I try to verify a **valid** receipt multiple times? Is it going to pass every time? What if the item is a consumable item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will pass every time - the receipt validation mechanism is designed to test only if a purchase was genuine, not whether it has been consumed or not. It's up to you to design your own app/middleware to handle consumable products.

A consumable product simply means when the user goes to purchase that same item iOS will allow them to buy it again, rather than showing a 'restore purchase' dialog. If they do buy a consumable product for a second time that receipt will be different from the first time they purchased.